# Common properties of herbs in creating anaphrodisiac effect?

Tags: botany, sexuality

Recently came across Wiki article about anaphrodisiac herbs and other products.

> An anaphrodisiac (also antaphrodisiac or antiaphrodisiac) is something
> that quells or blunts the libido. It is the opposite of an
> aphrodisiac, something that enhances sexual appetite. The word
> anaphrodisiac comes from the Greek privative prefix ἀν-, denoting
> negation, and aphrodisiac, from the Greek goddess of love, Aphrodite.
> [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphrodisiac)

The article mentioned some of the herbs and plant related putative anaphrodisiacs like,

- Marjoram (Origanum majorana) (Family: Lamiaceae)
- Humulus lupulus (Family: Cannabaceae)
- Heracleum mantegazzianum  (Family: Apiaceae)
- Morton Arboretum  (Family: Salicaceae)
- Vitex agnus-castus (Family: Lamiaceae)
- Ruta graveolens (Family: Rutaceae)
- Coriandrum sativum (Family:  Apiaceae)
- Tropaeolum tuberosum(Family:  Tropaeolaceae)

**I am not sure that is there any relevance in these claims that these herbs triggers anaphrodisiac effect.**

The question is,

Is there any common alkaloid, aromatic hydrocarbons or any other chemicals present in these herbs which triggers the anaphrodisiac effects ?

Comment: Why down vote ?

Comment: This might answer part of your question: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3731873/

Comment: @skymninge:Which part ?

Comment: I did not read all of it, but it looked to me like it mentioned at least some of the herbs and the chemicals you were asking for.

Comment: @skymninge - that article deals with aphrodisiacs